# Servlet output stream not flushing with jrun

Tags: servlets, outputstream, jrun

I'm attempting to use HTTP Streaming with a servlet. Locally I use orion as a servlet container and it works fine, but on the test server, which runs JRUN 4.0, the output is buffered even when I call flush() on the output stream. Any thoughts on why the output is being buffered and what I can do to stop it?

```
OutputStream os = servletResponse.getOutputStream();

while (true)
{
    //attempt to write to output before doing anything else. If browser has disconnected, an IOException will be thrown so nothing else will be done
    os.write(".".getBytes());
    os.flush();

    String response = getData();
    os.write(response.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why the difference, but did you try with `servletResponse.flushBuffer()`?

Comment: I believe that locally that did nothing, I had to flush the outputstream itself. I'll try that and see if it helps with jrun after the next test build

Comment: servletResponse.flushBuffer() didn't help